# How can I autoselect password boxes in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, passwords, autofill

I would like to make it so that every page that shows "password dots" is text-highlighted, so all I would have to do is press the "Enter" key and the password will be submitted. Is there a Firefox addon, or a script I can download/make to make this possible? Sorry for sounding completely ignorant I'm not very computer savvy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML should look like:

```
  <!--html above-->
  <input type='password' id='pass' name='pass' value='yourPasswordHere' />
  <!--more html below-->
  <script type='text/javascript' src='common.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You external JavaScript, saved as `common.js` should look something like:

```
function E(e){
  return document.getElementById(e);
}
E('pass').select();
```